# R using formatRound for all numeric columns of a datatable

Tags: r, datatable, tidyverse, dt

The following `R` code can be used to format the first four columns of `iris` data. Wondering how to format all numeric columns rather than giving their names or positions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

iris %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
  formatRound(1:4, digits = 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, we can do this before converting to `datatable`

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
iris %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), sprintf, fmt = '%.2f')) %>%
  datatable()
```

---

Or another option is to check the 'data' component in the created object

```
iris %>% 
     datatable()  %>%
     formatRound(purrr::map_lgl(.$x$data, is.numeric), digits = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for very useful answer. Please explain how you came to know about `.$x$data`.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I always check the `str` of the input data and the output.  Here, after converting to `datatable`, i checked the `str` to find the structure.  It is a nested list and thus was able to find the 'data' component nested within `x` list element

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
iris %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
  formatRound(which(sapply(iris,is.numeric)), digits = 2)
```